# Do we need SSL certificate for PayPal ExpressCheckout

Tags: ssl, paypal

We're using PayPal REST API for processing user transactions and recurring payments. In few weeks we are going online, and the last piece of information I need is SSL certificate. Do we need to install SSL certificate on our website in order to PayPal integration work well?

Thx!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PayPal, not computer programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, you do not have to install a SSL certificate on your website in order to work with PayPal API properly, but your server has to be able to establish secure connections with PayPal servers.